# pdfpages package and bibitem with my own counter

Tags: counters, pdfpages, bibitem

I have the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{cptnumpubli}
\def\numpubli{\addtocounter{cptnumpubli}{1}\thecptnumpubli}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{cptnumpubli}{0}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem[\numpubli]{refbib} authors, title
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the `\usepackage{pdfpages}` I get an error that I do not see how to handle.

It seems there is a conflict between the `pdfpages` package and using my own counter in the bibliography. I do not fully understand where the problem is comming from.

The compilation ends with the following message :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.16 \bibitem[\numpubli]{refbib}
                                 authors, title
```

How can I use the `pdfpages` package in my document, still using my own counter in the bibitem entries ?

Comment: Could you maybe include the error message in your question. It is often helpful in diagnosing the issue. And welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the error message. Tks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? `\bibitem{refbib}` already adds numbers by default. `pdfpages` are not relevant here, the `calc` package is (`pdfpages` loads `calc`)

Comment: The MWE is part of a longer report containing a long bibliography which I would like control the numbering (the bibliography is splitted over several sections). The `pdfpages` package is used to insert pages in the report from some pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing lines

```
\newcounter{cptnumpubli}
\def\numpubli{\addtocounter{cptnumpubli}{1}\thecptnumpubli}
```

by

```
\newcounter{cptnumpubli}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\numpubli}{\addtocounter{cptnumpubli}{1}\thecptnumpubli}
```

makes it work !

[Edit feb. 2021]

And I found that the following works even better (the solution with `DeclareRobustCommand` makes troubles with the `\cite` command) :

```
\newcounter{cptnumpubli}
\def\numpubli{\protect\stepcounter{cptnumpubli}\thecptnumpubli}
```